# VAR with trend-stationary variables

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression, trend, cointegration

I'm currently trying to estimate a VAR with 3 variables - consumption, investment and a credit spread. I have inspected the variables and run ADF tests to determine that they are in-fact trend-stationary rather than processes with a unit root. On running a Johansen test to check if they cointegrate, I find that the LR equilibrium matrix has a rank of 1. I have 2 questions:

1. Does it make sense to run a cointegration test on trend stationary variables?
2. In order to estimate the VAR, should I detrend the variables and use the detrended data in my estimation?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know I was meant to do that, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it does not make sense to run a cointegration test on trend stationary variables. Cointegration requires variables with unit roots.
2. You can either detrend the variables beforehand or include a trend in the VAR model as an exogenous regressor.